# Should I use rel="noindex nofollow noopener or rel="nofollow noopener, to noindex a pdf on my page?

Tags: indexing, nofollow, noindex

So,

I have seen an error on my search console that a few pages are not indexing due to presence of this tag (rel="noindex nofollow noopener). I have used these tags to noindex a particular pdf on my page. Here is the page link - https://career.guru99.com/fr/top-15-painter-interview-questions/.

Now this tag (rel="noindex nofollow noopener) is present on my other pages also but those pages are indexing. Here is the link to that page - https://career.guru99.com/top-15-painter-interview-questions/.

Please help in this case what is right?

I have used this tag (rel="noindex nofollow noopener) but due to this my whole page is not indexing - https://career.guru99.com/fr/top-15-painter-interview-questions/.

Same tag is used in my previous pages but those are indexing - https://career.guru99.com/top-15-painter-interview-questions/